# What Rails load to memory before it reaches some 'limit'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, heroku

I have a Rails application which uses ~550 mb after 3-4 hours of use and stays there for the rest of the day, which leads me to thought that it's it normal way how Rails use memory. 
Here is [screenshot of my memory usage from Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYnRp.png) and [Gemfile.lock](https://gist.github.com/VladFarion/ef2e025618a44866ecaecf9e46bd0384)
My goal - reduce app memory usage. For this I need to understand what parts add to this memory usage. I looked through various articles in Interenet on Ruby\Rails memory usage topic.
I used derailed_benchmarks 'mem' command to track down what is large at boot. Basically, I have two questions:

- Why my memory usage goes upto some **N** mb value and not more or less? How I can calculate that value?
- Assume we have some gem which consumes 20mb. How much times does it added to overall usage?

If there any information that can help my issue, I would be very thankful to you.